# MSDeploy fails with "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: msdeploy

The following MSDeploy string supplied to the command line results in an error. Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='D:\dev\Project\obj\BuildConfiguration\Package\Project.zip' -dest:auto='Website Name',computerName='computername',userName='username',password='password' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -allowUntrusted -debug
```

Stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentUnavailableException: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://computername/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE'.
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.CreateStatusThread(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)    at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.ExecuteWorker() Error count: 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause was a mixture of things - an internal DNS resolution issue, meant the hostname was resolving to the wrong IP, plus we have to use IIS6, and I believe there to be a problem with the hosting of the http agent required for msdeploy on the same port as existing websites.

The resolution was to specify the IP expicitly, and re-install the deployment service (WebDeploy) from the command line, specifying a custom endpoint to avoid the IIS conflict.

My working incantation:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=D:\Path\obj\Configuration\Package\Project.zip -dest:auto,computerName='http://192.168.x.xxx:8090/MsDeployAgentService2/' -allowUntrusted  -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="Website Name In IIS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of the "msdeploy.exe Error: 0....System.IO.IOException: **Unable to write**....connection was forcibly closed by the remote host...." error is if one of the binary website files is actively running and therefore cannot be overwritten.  This could happen if even just 1 .dll file is currently writing to a log file.  One solution is to stop the website, then do the MSDeploy, although that is not an optimal solution b/c in production you cannot let the website be down for a couple minutes while the new version is deployed...